# Motivation non-negativity constraint KKT conditions

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am having problems understanding the non-negativity constraint on the Lagrange multiplier in the KKT conditions. Why does the sign matter?

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions#Nonlinear_optimization_problem) link for statement of the KKT conditions.

I do understand that it's about dual feasibility, but why is dual feasibility defined this way?

Is there an intuitive way to explain this constraint on $\mu\geq0$?

Thank you!